# How to print the body content of a html page using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to print all the body content of a html file using sed. I have found a pattern in the internet, but not able to understand how it is working.
pattern is

```
/<body>/,/<\/body>/
```

I am not able to understand how it is working.... how it is taking that start with body line and print until the  would come.

Someone please explain this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one-liner you're using prints all the lines between the first line that matches the regular expression `<body>` and the first line that matches the regular expression `</body>`. It uses a range match that matches all lines starting from a line that matches the first pattern and ending with the first line that matches the second pattern.

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' file
```

- `-n` suppresses automatic printing of pattern space and `p` prints the current pattern space.

Similar to the sed command, you can specify the starting pattern and ending pattern using Perl.

```
perl -ne 'print if /pattern1/ .. /pattern2/' file
```

Comment: sed works line by line. In this case, the line that have `pattern1` is read and activate the filter to go further (`p` here) and sed do this until it found a NEW line having `pattern2`. So if pattern 1 and 2 are on the same line, sed never found this end and print until next occurence of pattern2 or end of file. Sed also have a buffer to keep in memory info between lines but not used here so yes it does work as a one line printer in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The sed command first takes the start pattern and checks for the lines which matches the start pattern. If a line is matched, then it prints the current line and all the upcoming lines until a line which matches the end pattern is printed.

```
/start pattern/,/end pattern/
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
foo
blah
bar
blah
blah
foo
bar
$ sed -n '/foo/,/bar/p' file
foo
blah
bar
foo
bar
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some `awk` variations:

This prints from `START` to `END`, but not `START` nor `END`

```
awk '/START/{f=1;next} /END/{f=0} f' file
```

```
awk '/END/{f=0} f; /START/{f=1}' file
```

This prints starting with `START` and to and inclusive `END`

```
awk '/START/{f=1} /END/{f=0;print} f' file
```

```
awk '/START/{f=1} f; /END/{f=0}' file
```

```
awk '/START/,/END/' file
```